# Get DocumentSnapshot by its id from Firebase collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get DocumentSnapshot from collection

this my code

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamState() => collectionRef.snapshots();
```

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: auth.streamState(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if (snapshot.hasData){
        DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs.elementAt(0);

        print(doc.id);
      }

      return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
);
```

it work fine but as you see I use elementAt(0)
I want to get doc by its id

I try with docs.where but fail.

Comment: What is `auth.streamState()` in the code you shared?

Comment: Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamState() => collectionRef.snapshots();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the ID of the document you want to listen to, you can do:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamState() => collectionRef.doc("the document ID").snapshots();
```

And then the `StreamBuilder` becomes:

```
return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  stream: auth.streamState(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> asyncSnapshot){
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasData){
      DocumentSnapshot doc = asyncSnapshot.data!;
      print(doc.id);
    }

    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: my problem is I want to get info from another document , when I listen to one document I can't reach to another info from another document

Comment: The code in my answer is the shortest way to get a document by its ID from Firestore and show it in a `StreamBuilder`, which is what you asked in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The data that you are getting from auth.streamState() is I suppose about authentication? You should get it by id there probably

Comment: Stream<QuerySnapshot> streamState() => collectionRef.snapshots(); _____ auth Provider class

Answer (score 1):

it will return all documents

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: auth.streamState(),
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
if (snapshot.hasData){
 return GridView.builder(
gridDelegate:
const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
mainAxisExtent: 200,
childAspectRatio: 1 / 1,
crossAxisSpacing: 1,
mainAxisSpacing: 1,
crossAxisCount: 2),
itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
print("${snapshot.data?.docs[index]["feildNameYouWant"]}");
return Text("${snapshot.data?.docs[index]["feildNameYouWant"]}");
},
);
}else{
print("snapshot DONT hasData ");
return CustomWidgetYouWant();

}
);}
```